# Enumerating Certificate Fields in C#

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, certificate

How do you enumerate the fields of a certificate help in a store. Specifically, I am trying to enumerate the fields of personal certificates issued to the logged on user.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
...
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
foreach(var cert in store.Certificates)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You also must use **store.open()** before you can access the store.